# How to get Lowest price of Stock in Google Finance for the past 6 months

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I want to use Google Sheets to find the lowest price a stock has reached in the last 6 months.

I have tried various formulas:

=googlefinance("NSE:RELIANCE", "close", Today()-365,125)

- it shows full previous year data with date columns.

=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:RELIANCE","price",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-6,DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))

- it shows only price column no dates

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something like this =let(x,googlefinance("NSE:RELIANCE", "close", Today()-182,182),filter(x,choosecols(x,2)=min(choosecols(x,2))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,googlefinance("NSE:RELIANCE","price",today()-180,today()),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)=min(index(Σ,,2))))
```

Comment: But is the last 6 month presented in 180 days or some other number, as the trading day are different than the Annual calendar days

Comment: And how to remove the time stamp? Just the date only

Comment: Sorry I dont get your first question. coming to second one, easy way is to select the timestamp cell & use `Format`>`Number`>`Date`